# How do you write "evaluate at" in Latex?

Tags: math-mode

I have trouble rewriting the following in Latex :

[image]

Thanks in advance !

Comment: `$(\alpha_t)_{t=0}^1$`

Comment: Im a GOM (Grumpy Old Man). This is not a "do it for me site". Provide a MWE that we can compile that shows your problem and how you tried to fix it.

Comment: Enter "evaluated at" in the site search bar and you will see numerous possibly relevant posts. There are too many to cite here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: I may have misunderstood the question. If you want exactly as shown in your post:

```
(\alpha_t)^{1}_{t=0}
```

**Original answer**:
It is by no means the perfect answer and has some issues, but in my custom preamble I have the following, which includes square parentheses:

```latex
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\evallinehelper}[1]{[}{\vert}{\mathopen{}#1\mathopen{}\delimsize]\!}
\ProvideDocumentCommand{\evalline}{m m m}{\ensuremath{\evallinehelper*{#1}_{#2}^{#3}}}
```

An example is:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\evallinehelper}[1]{[}{\vert}{\mathopen{}#1\mathopen{}\delimsize]\!}
\ProvideDocumentCommand{\evalline}{m m m}{\ensuremath{\evallinehelper*{#1}_{#2}^{#3}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \evalline{\frac{d}{dx} f(x)}{x=1}{}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: example image]

Comment: Are the square brackets around `\frac{d}{dx}f(x)` needed? I guess in some notational systems.

Comment: I think it's easier to read with the square brackets. Thanks u for your help !